# Is it possible to generate RDoc documentation from Java classes exposed via JRuby?

Tags: jruby, rdoc

I have existing Java classes which are exposed to Ruby scripts via JRuby and I would like to be able to provide RDoc-style documentation to the Ruby developers who will be using the java objects.

Is it possible to generate RDoc documentation from the Java classes? Or will I need to maintain/generate a stub version of them as ruby classes which can have standard RDoc executed against them?